# Exact URL to access the Windows Phone Bing Search?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to access the Bing search by creating a WebBroswerTask that then enters a URL that would redirect to the Bing Services available on the phone.

I noticed that if you leave no URL and enter a common phrase you are redirected to Bing Services in IE on WP7.

Now I want to do this on my App.  What is the URL to access this function.

If not, any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're actually meaning to use `SearchTask`.  [How to search and browse the web](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/4-how-to-search-and-browse-the-web-in-a-wp7-app)

Comment: Thank you, you will not be assimilated today :D